# How do I send the value of field_1 and field_2 to an MVC controller using jQuery

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ajax, jquery

I asked this question before but my answers were not for MVC. I will try again. Sorry if my question is not good as English is not my native language.

I want to send the value of some fields:

```
field_1
field_2
Field_3
```

To the server using Ajax.

Is there a way I can do it using jQuery? Note that sometime it's fields 1-3 and sometime maybe more fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, this is possible. What it sounds like you want to do is pass an array of strings to an MVC Action, perhaps something like this:

```
public class MyController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult DoSomething(string[] strings)
    {
       return Json(new {success = true});
    }
}
```

You can use a `JsonResult` in an ActionResult to return JSON encoded values, in this case an anonymous type.

To do this in jQuery, the code would look something like this:

```
function doSomething() {
     var items = ['item1','item2','item3'];
     $.ajax({
         type: 'POST',
         url: 'http://mysite/MyController/DoSomething',
         data: items,
         dataType: 'application/json',
         success: function() {/*handle success here */}
     });
}
```

Here, all you have to do is populate the `items` array with the values you want, perhaps y asking the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

you can use something like this:

[in your View]

```
<script>
var actionUrlHere='@Url.Action("ActionName", "ControllerName")';
$.post(actionUrlHere,
    {
        fieldname_1: fieldValue_1,
        fieldname_2: fieldValue_2,
        fieldname_3: fieldValue_3,
    });
</script>
```

[In controller]

```
[HttpPost]
public void AjaxInputSave(string fieldname_1, string fieldname_2, fieldname_3)
    {
...your logic here...
}
```

or if you want to send array:
[in your View]

```
<script>
var actionUrlHere='@Url.Action("ActionName", "ControllerName")';
var fieldArrayValue = [111,222,333,444];
$.post(actionUrlHere,
    {
        fieldArrayName: fieldArrayValue
    });
</script>
```

[In controller]

```
[HttpPost]
public void AjaxInputSave(int [] fieldArrayName)
    {
...your logic here...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my $0.02 worth. You might wanna check out @ScottGu's article on the subject. It might be helpfull.This is with respect to MVC3. Here's the link http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/27/introducing-asp-net-mvc-3-preview-1.aspx

Hope this sheds some light